# In the CSS file, how is the url supposed to be structured for the svg format of a font?

Tags: html, css, svg, fonts

### Objective

To implement the svg format of the font in my project

### Background

Just making sure that I am setting the path correctly. I can view the font on my browsers as I did the `@font-face` to include the various font files. I used what was suggested when i downloaded the font. But I am just making sure that that SVG portion is correct.

I browsed around and found [**Using @font-face**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/) at CSS Tricks. It gave this example:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

But that seems very clear cut unless you have the fonts in a subdirectory. In my case I have

```
url('../assets/fonts/din/din-regular-webfont.svg#din-regular-webfont') format('svg');
```

This is how I am currently using the fonts

### index.html

```
<!-- in the head -->
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="css/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<!-- in a paragraph that uses the font -->
<p class="fnt-din-regular">This is: DIN Regular</p>
```

### main.css

.fnt-din-regular {
    font-family: 'DIN_Regular';
}

### fonts.css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'DIN_Regular';
    src: url('../assets/fonts/din/din-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../assets/fonts/din/din-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../assets/fonts/din/din-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../assets/fonts/din/din-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../assets/fonts/din/din-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../assets/fonts/din/din-regular-webfont.svg#din-regular-webfont') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

But is that last part correct? should it remain

```
url('../assets/fonts/din/din-regular-webfont.svg#din-regular-webfont') format('svg');
```

or be

```
url('../assets/fonts/din/din-regular-webfont.svg#DIN_Regular') format('svg');
```

I don't understand what happens after the hash. Please explain why this is wrong or correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the SVG font in a text editor, you should see that there is a `<font>...</font>` element within it.

That element should have an `id` attribute that you will use as after the `#` in the URL, e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<svg width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1"
 xmlns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
  <defs>
    <font id="Font2" horiz-adv-x="1000">
      ...
    </font>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

In the example above, the URL would be something like:

```
url('../assets/fonts/din/din-regular-webfont.svg#Font2') format('svg');
```